# Parse whole html document and replace specific parts of it automatically PHP

Tags: php, html, replace, parsing, document

Greetings,

Iv'e made a rapid search in the previous questions but did not find an adequate answer for my question.

I have create a function that finds words in an array library and replace these by links to the description of the word.

Example :

```
$words = array("ANTIM","APDIV","APVEG","ARCHE","ARFEU","ARMUR",
"ARSUP","ARTHE","ARTIL","ASSOM","ATTSU","BANQU","BARDE","BRICO",
"CAMOU","CHANC","CHAOM");
```

When I call my function, replace_text($someString). I search for these words in the text. Although these words are in several pages of my website and all need to link to there respective description. I made that function in order to automate the process and not write the links manually.

So when I call :

```
replace_text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices congue condimentum. Integer tempor aliquam ARFEU nisi at adipiscing. Vivamus ornare consequat metus. Nulla mollis lacus sit amet dolor rutrum sollicitudin. Maecenas sit amet nibh ut turpis bibendum rutrum et a tellus. Fusce a tortor a lacus feugiat gravida. Suspendisse elementum hendrerit urna ut viverra. Pellentesque ARCHE auctor, metus vitae lobortis vestibulum, justo ligula ultrices magna, vitae blandit mauris sapien eu velit. Nullam dapibus tristique orci, ac ullamcorper lectus venenatis ARTIL non. Nulla laoreet laoreet pretium.")
```

This will be replaced by :

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices congue condimentum. Integer tempor aliquam <a href="somelink">ARFEU</a nisi at adipiscing. Vivamus ornare consequat metus. Nulla mollis lacus sit amet dolor rutrum sollicitudin. Maecenas sit amet nibh ut turpis bibendum rutrum et a tellus. Fusce a tortor a lacus feugiat gravida. Suspendisse elementum hendrerit urna ut viverra. Pellentesque <a href="somelink">ARCHE</a auctor, metus vitae lobortis vestibulum, justo ligula ultrices magna, vitae blandit mauris sapien eu velit. Nullam dapibus tristique orci, ac ullamcorper lectus venenatis <a href="somelink">ARTIL</a> non. Nulla laoreet laoreet pretium."
```

(The words found from the array were replaced with anchors.)

Finally, I want my function to be called but by searching within my whole pages (html code) automatically when loaded. I think this can be done with the domDocument part of PHP but I am not used to it, can you guide me please ?

Comment: What do you mean automatically when loaded? You want the function to run even if the page doesn't call it?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, here is what i want to archive :
1-Replace text within my whole html document when page is loaded.

The difficulties I encounter at the moment :
1-How to retrieve the whole content of the current page
2-How to parse this content through my simple function that uses str_replace()

Comment: Where would you put the function if you want the current page? Wouldn't the whole content include the function itself? Do you want to redirect the document request to another script that parses the requested document and then output? We'd need to know your HTTP server to advise on that.

Comment: I run an Apache server, and you are right, I never though of the way to call the function. I have though of a PHP class that would be included on every page.. but that wouldn't work at all. Maybe the best way is to parse the files manually :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

You can create your function, lets say

```
 function call_back_addLinks($buffer){
    //do your magic and replace
    //words with links in $buffer
    //then return the new String
 }
```

Then:

```
 ob_start("call_back_addLinks");
```

Then your normal PHP code to generate normal content. That is, your entire page here.

Then:

```
 ob_end_flush();
```

The link has a simple example.

Comment: I'll try this method... although I think I found an easy way out. I may use the following :

$content = file_get_contents('./my-content-page.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo my_replace_text_function($content);

This seems to be working correctly... Ill test and inform you !